# Get the entire assembly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to eliminate a call from my API in which the end-user has to pass `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` in their code, currently my code looks lke the following.

```
public static Dictionary<int, Packet> Packets { get; private set; }

public static void Init()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.BaseType == typeof(Packet))
        {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

However this only gets all of the classes that are available in the API.dll, and none of the classes from the project that's using the .dll are included,

However if I pass it as a paramter, like so:

```
 public static void Init(Assembly assembly) {}
```

it loads everything just fine, is this intended behaviour, is there a way to do this all in the background without the end-user ever having to worry about the Assmebly call?

**In a nutshell** - I have a .dll file that people will be using in their projects, I want to get all of the classes from the project that's using the .dll, not all of the classes inside of the .dll

Comment: You could have them pass an array or List of the Types.  NET does it this way for UITypeEditors where it needs to know what is allowed/not.  Similar issue since it doesnt know if the call is being invoked from the main assembly or a DLL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it as simple as [Assembly.GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you limiting your clients to have to define their `Packet` classes in a single assembly?  What if a client wants to implement different types of `Packet` classes in different assemblies?   What if someone wants to do run time code generation and create a `Packet` class at runtime?

Your API shouldn't care where or how Packet classes are defined.  It should just expose an interface that will allow clients to register new `Packet` types directly.  That will give clients the maximum flexibility.

Now it would be appropriate to provider helper methods so that clients could register types from assemblies or from the [calling assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Something like:

```
class PacketRegistration {
    public void RegisterPacketType(Type packetType) {...}

    public void RegisterPacketType<TPacket>() where TPacket:Packet { 
         RegisterPacket(typeof(TPacket)); 
    }

    public void RegisterPacketTypesFromAssembly(Assembly assembly) {...}

    public void RegisterPacketTypesFromCurrentAssembly() {
        RegisterPacketTypesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
    }
```

Comment: The reasoning for using a single assembly in my API is because it's for use with Unity3D, and if anybody is using multiple assemblies in Unity, I'd like them to teach me how.  -- This is a great answer is most cases, but doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Christian.tucker Perhaps you should be asking *that* question instead!